# Use of undefined constant (input) laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am junior developer and  got stucked with such problem:
Laravel brings me back an error: "Use of undefined constant input - assumed 'input'"
And I dont understand why: this variable is IN javascript code.

Here it is:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('pac-input', 'Адрес') !!}
        {!! Form::text('pac-input', $meta ? $meta->pac-input:old('pac-input', null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Введите адрес']) !!}
    </div>
```

My input

```
var input = (
                document.getElementById('pac-input'));

                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

My JavaScript code (google.maps.api3)

Also got a question: in the source there was a comment after

```
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input'));
```

What kind of `HTMLInputElement` this one wants?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

Replace

```
$meta->pac-input
```

with

```
$meta->pac->input
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here is `-`

Laravel blade templating sees your variable `$meta->pac-input` as `$meta->pac` and `-input` instead of `$meta->pac-input` as a single variable.

So you might want to change you code into,

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('pac_input', 'Адрес') !!}
    {!! Form::text('pac_input', $meta ? $meta->pac_input:old('pac_input', null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'pac_input' 'placeholder' => 'Введите адрес']) !!}
</div>
```